# Control proportions in size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am annotating a plot with

```
plt.annotate(
    size,
    xy=(x, y),
    xycoords='data',
    xytext=(x, y + 10),
    textcoords='data',
    horizontalalignment='center',
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle="->")
)
```

where `size` is the number I want to output near the arrow.

This annotation works but if the `y` values are very high, the shift on `10` is not enough and if the `values` are very small, `10` is way too much.

I guess it could be small improvement to let the shift be `y * 1.1` instead of `y + 10`; however, I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Ideally, the value `size` influences the shift, so larger values `size` implies longer arrows but still in reasonable proportions. There could hypothetically be great differences among different values of `size` so if the shift was `y + size ** 2`, it could become real ugly with large differences among different values of `size`.

Comment: Seems like placing an if condition and using the values mentioned- y*1.1 and y+size**2 for the two cases (small and large size values) should do the job.